# Installation Failed after creating UWP with Desktop App Converter

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I decided to have another crack at converting my tool (https://github.com/mikecann/Windows7-Taskbar-Monitor) to a windows store app using the Desktop App Converter.

Things I did this time:

1) Force-updated my machine to the anniversary update.
2) Downloaded Desktop App Converter and .wim file.
3) Setup the base image .wim
4) Ran the converter on my self-extracting installer with the following:

.\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -Installer C:\tmp\TaskbarSystemMonitorInstaller.exe -InstallerArguments "/T:c:\out /C" -Destination C:\Out2 -PackageName "TaskbarSystemMonitor" -Publisher "CN=mikecann.co.uk" -Version 0.0.0.1 -MakeAppx -Verbose -AppExecutable C:\Out2\TaskbarSystemMonitor.exe -Sign

5) I get a .appx file but when I try to run it I get:

[image]

6) This is my first winows store app so im not sure exactly what I need to do cert wise. So I decided to have a go at uploading it to the store, but I get the following errors:

[image]

7) I dont know what to do about the first error, the second and third error I tihnk I can fix, the fourth error im not sure about.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 5) I get a .appx file but when I try to run it I get

Ref **Appx package deployment** section in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-deploy-and-debug)

1. In File Explorer, right click an appx that you've signed with a test cert and choose **Properties** from the context menu.
2. Click or tap the **Digital Signatures** tab.
3. Click or tap on the certificate and choose **Details**.
4. Click or tap **View Certificate**.
5. Click or tap **Install Certificate**.
6. In the **Store Location** group, select **Local Machine**.
7. Click or tap **Next** and **OK** to confirm the UAC dialog.
8. In the next screen of the Certificate Import Wizard, change the selected option to **Place all certificates in the following store**.
9. Click or tap **Browse**. In the Select Certificate Store window, scroll down and select **Trusted People** and click or tap **OK**.
10. Click or tap **Next**. A new screen appears. Click or tap **Finish**.
11. A confirmation dialog should appear. If so, click **OK**. If a different dialog indicates that there is a problem with the certificate, you may need to do some certificate troubleshooting.
    Note: For Windows to trust the certificate, the certificate must be located in either the **Certificates (Local Computer) > Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates** node or the **Certificates (Local Computer) > Trusted People > Certificates** node. Only certificates in these two locations can validate the certificate trust in the context of the local machine. Otherwise, an error message that resembles the following string appears:

> "Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x800B0109, A
>   certificate chain processed, but terminated in a rootcertificate which
>   is not trusted by the trust provider. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800B0109) error 0x800B0109: The root certificate of the signature in
>   the app package must be trusted."

---

> So I decided to have a go at uploading it to the store, but I get the following errors

You need to get a valid certification from Windows Store and resign your app before publishing. Using the `-Sign` flag in the Desktop App Converter will auto-generate a testing certificate. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter#deploy-your-converted-appx)

**-----Update(09/14/2016)------**

About publishing Desktop Bridge Apps, please also see the very important part which described [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/08/02/windows-10-anniversary-update-sdk-14393/#ewlAu8GMyGFpvRvL.97)

> In addition, we will begin the process of accepting apps using the
>   Desktop Bridge. While we build the pipeline into the Windows Store to
>   publish these apps, our team will work directly with developers to get
>   their converted apps and games into the Windows Store. **Contact our
>   team
>   [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge)**
>   if you are interested in submitting an app using the Desktop Bridge to
>   the Windows Store.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, ill look more into this soon :)

Comment: @mikeysee About publishing Desktop Bridge Apps, please also check my latest updates for some important things

Comment: thanks for that, I have submitted a request to that page now.

Comment: I just tried your process and it works! Amazing! Thanks :D

Comment: Been over a week now and not heard anything back, app is pretty much ready to go, how long does it normally take?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT: Thanks. Your solution to the first item helped me. But I have no idea why the DesktopAppConverter's **-Sign** parameter didn't work. Do I need to do this every time I build an APPX?