# How to sign AppX from Desktop App Converter

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, appx, desktop-bridge

I have been trying to sign the AppX generated by the D.A.C. in order to verify it works as expected, but it seems a self signed certificate is not enough.

I also tried to sign using my Comodo SHA256 certificate, but even if I make sure to use the same publisher name as the certificate in the manifest, I get

```html
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024885/0x8007000b)
```

I am starting to wonder if this does not mean I have to use Authenticode.

I would very much appreciate advice about what should be done by others who have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been trying to sign the AppX generated by the D.A.C. in order to verify it works as expected, but it seems a self signed certificate is not enough.

We can use the `-Sign` flag when running the DAC to automatically sign your .appx package. Please see the details in [Sign your converted desktop app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-signing)

To deply the converted app, please notice the certificate should be installed on this machine, see my answer in [Installation Failed after creating UWP with Desktop App Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423656/installation-failed-after-creating-uwp-with-desktop-app-converter/39450787#39450787)

> I am starting to wonder if this does not mean I have to use Authenticode

Yes, the Authenticode programs include MakeCert, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364(v=vs.85).aspx)

------------Update(09/25/2016)-----------

> Deploy your application using the add-appxpackage –register AppxManifest.xml cmdlet or by repackaging it using MakeAppx, see App packager (MakeAppx.exe)

Please locate to the Appx layout folder which contains **AppxManifest.xml** file, after updating this file to contain a reference to the VCLibs UWPDesktop framework package, open Powershell(as Administrator) and type:

```
add-appxpackage –register AppxManifest.xml
```

**Note: if the package has been installed on this device, please uninstall it first, otherwise you will see the conflict exception**

Comment: I tried the -Sign option but yet, the AppC cannot run.

Comment: @MitchMatch what's the meaning of "can not run"?how did you deploy

Comment: I simply double click on the AppX and click Install.

Comment: @MitchMatch then you could install the package on your machine?

Comment: No, I could not install, it says I have to get in touch with the developer. I am now reading your page about using the AppX with a self-signed certificate. I am going to follow it step by step. Thank you.

Comment: @MitchMatch all right, please follow my steps to install the certificate, then you can install the appx smoothly

Comment: New hurdle. After following your guidelines, I get this when I tried to launch:
Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict with a package already installed, or it depends on things not installed here (package dependencies), or is made for a different architecture (0x80073CF3)

Comment: I reran the converter, and indeed there is an issue with dependencies:       
Warning Summary:
W_PACKAGE_DEPENDENCY_ADDED
A dependency on framework package 'Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.UWPDesktop' was added to the AppxManifest.xml. See 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821959' for guidance on installing the package prior to local deployment. Otherwise, if this is in error, remove the corresponding entry from Dependencies in the AppxManifest.xml before packaging and deploying your application.

Comment: @MitchMatch please follow the steps: Referencing the VC Runtime framework packages from converted desktop apps in that blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/07/07/using-visual-c-runtime-in-centennial-project/

Comment: Alright. I see. Will follow that scrupulously. Thank you Franklin. You advanced me greatly.

Comment: Confused by this sentence : "Deploy your application using the add-appxpackage –register AppxManifest.xml cmdlet or by repackaging it using MakeAppx, see App packager (MakeAppx.exe).

Comment: Does it mean I should launch my existing converted AppX from the command line with the add -appxpackage option ? How ?

Comment: @MitchMatch Please see my updated answer **Update(09/25/2016)**